# Is there a purely algebraic proof that the sequence $a_N:=\left(\frac{N!}{N^N}\right)^\frac{1}{N} $ is monotone decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, monotone-functions

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4851296/show-that-n-ln-n-n-lnnn1-lnn1-n) and I quickly noticed that the first inequality (after using $e^x$ on both sides)   $\frac{N^N}{e^N}< N!$ can be written as $\frac{N!}{N^N}> e^{-N}$ or  $\left(\frac{N!}{N^N}\right)^\frac{1}{N}> \frac{1}{e}$. This I want to prove in the end.

The famous limit $\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\left(\frac{N!}{N^N}\right)^\frac{1}{N}= \frac{1}{e}$ will play a role in a purely algebraic proof, because if I can prove that the sequence $a_N:=\left(\frac{N!}{N^N}\right)^\frac{1}{N} $ is monotone decreasing, this will mean that $a_N > \frac{1}{e}$. But I couldn't find a proof.
I tried to use the AM-GM inequality to prove that $\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}}{n} > \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}}$
and failed because it will result in a much more complicated problem.

The graphing calculator  suggests that this sequence is indeed monotone decreasing (for all $x$).
[image]

Although Mittens gave a good proof to the linked question, which of course counts as a proof to this question, I wonder if there is a purely algebraic proof that the sequence  $a_N:=\left(\frac{N!}{N^N}\right)^\frac{1}{N} $ is monotone decreasing **without** using integrals.

Comment: Algebraic is more aboutt identities; Calculus is probably when one needs (differential if you want to avoid integration)

Comment: It is interesting to notice that if $A_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$,
$$\lim_n\sqrt[n]{A_n}=\lim_n\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}=\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^{-n}$$ and that $(1+1/n)^{-n}\searrow e^{-1}$. Also, $A_{n+1}<A_n$ ans so, $A^{1/n}_{n+1}<A^{1/n}_n$.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4492404) help? It reduces to the problem of showing that the sequence $$\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n$$ is increasing which can be done via AM-GM.

Comment: @pie: It seems that your question is answered in the positive [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4492404/121671) using induction.

Comment: @Mittens This is what I linked as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a purely algebratic proof for that.

**Lemma 1.**
$$(n+2)\ln(n+1)-(n+1)\ln(n+2)<n\ln n-(n-1)\ln(n+1)$$
**Proof.**
By AM-GM we have
$$(n+1)^nn<\left(\frac{n(n+1)+n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=\left(\frac{n^2+2n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$
$$\ln n+n\ln(n+1)<(n+1)\ln(n^2+2n)-(n+1)\ln(n+1)$$
$$\ln n+n\ln(n+1)<(n+1)\ln(n+2)+(n+1)\ln n-(n+1)\ln(n+1)$$
$$(2n+1)\ln(n+1)<(n+1)\ln(n+2)+n\ln n$$
**QED.**

**Lemma 2.**
$$n(n+1)\ln n-n^2\ln(n+1)<\ln(n!)$$
**Proof.** By mathematical induction:

When $n=1$, $-\ln2<0$ is true.

Assume it's true for $n$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(n+1)(n+2)\ln(n+1)-(n+1)^2\ln(n+2)\\
=&(n+1)((n+2)\ln(n+1)-(n+1)\ln(n+2))\\
<&(n+1)(n\ln n-(n-1)\ln(n+1))\\
=&n(n+1)\ln n-n^2\ln(n+1)+\ln(n+1)\\
<&\ln(n!)+\ln(n+1)\\
=&\ln((n+1)!)
\end{aligned}
$$
so it's true for $n+1$.

**QED.**
$$n(n+1)\ln n-n^2\ln(n+1)<\ln(n!)$$
$$n\ln(n!)-n^2\ln(n+1)<(n+1)\ln(n!)-n(n+1)\ln n$$
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\ln(n!)-\frac{n}{n+1}\ln(n+1)<\frac{1}{n}\ln(n!)-\ln n$$
$$\frac{1}{n+1}(\ln(n!)-n\ln(n+1))<\frac{1}{n}(\ln(n!)-n\ln n)$$
$$\left(\dfrac{n!}{(n+1)^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}<\left(\dfrac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$\left(\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}<\left(\dfrac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Which is $a_{n+1}<a_n$.